# Replace scene with react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm building my first app in react native and am using router flux for navigation. I have a tab bar with a login tab/component. After pressing the login button I would like to replace this login tab with a logout tab which leads to another scene (a logout scene). Please see this [image of the login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXumK.png) with the tab bar on the bottom of the screen

How do I do that? Should I use something like Redux?

I've tried doing something like:

```
onLogin = () => {
    Actions.refresh({component: {Logout}});
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you build the tab bar ? is it a separate component?

Comment: I am using the "built in" tab bar of the router flux module.